# Suppresion de réplication sql-server impossible, sp_removedbreplication crashes

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

Following the restoration of a replicated database onto another replicated database, the sp_removedbreplication fails.

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MScheck_dropobject, Line 9 [Batch starting line 0]
Invalid object name 'dbo.sysextendedarticlesview'.
Msg 3724, Level 16, State 3, Procedure sys.sp_MSdrop_peertopeer_tables, Line 32 [Batch starting line 0]
Cannot drop the table 'dbo.MSpeer_lsns' because it is being used for replication.
```

The problem is that when configuring the replications, I added ALL tables with a primary key, even tables like dbo.MSpeer_lsns.

Today I find myself stuck; sp_replicationdboption produces a similar error, and I don't have a "clean" database to restore. How can I "clean all this up"?

Thank you very much

Comment: I don't really understand your situation or why you're mucking about with system tables, but what is your end goal that you're trying to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.